# How can you use subdirectories in a GitHub wiki checkout?

Tags: github, wiki, gollum-wiki

I'd like to organize my GitHub wiki pages in subdirectories.  How do we refer to the pages in subdirectories?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

github wiki / [gollum-wiki](https://github.com/github/gollum) doesn't inherently provide anything explicit for organizing pages into sub-directories. Any page can be linked from any other page irrespective of where it logically belongs. This is a powerful feature that makes wikis very flexible.

One way to implement a sub-directories structure would be to follow a naming convention.

Example: Having all pages related to `subject1` have names that start with `subject1`, and so on.