# How to structure GitHub wiki files?

Tags: github, filesystems, wiki

I have cloned one of my GitHub project's wiki locally, and I want to restructure the file system. By default different pages added to the wiki are all created in the parent directory:

```
/wiki
     home.md
     wiki_page_1.md
     ...
```

I want have a directory structure similar to this:

```
/wiki
  /setup
    setup_procedures.md
    index.md
  /development
    index.md
    tools.md
  /images
    front_page.png
```

I've tried to structure my wiki files similarly, but it's not working for the `.md` files. However, it works for the images folder. Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: For what it's worth, I've seen a team address this concern by dispensing with the Wiki proper and instead maintaining their .md files within the code repository. They created a Docs sub-folder (and folders) for .md files and a single designated sub-folder for all images and attachments, Wiki linking to them as needed. I wasn't crazy about the UX but, it seemed to work for them.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If GitHub is still using [github/gollum](https://github.com/github/gollum), then, as explained in "[How can you use subdirectories in a GitHub wiki checkout?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14408376/6309)", subfolders are not supported (or were buggy at the time of the fork).

More recent versions of [gollum/gollum](https://github.com/gollum/gollum) [supports that organization](https://github.com/gollum/gollum/wiki#repo-structure), even though recent PR (Pull Requests) are still fixing issues around it (like [PR 787](https://github.com/gollum/gollum/pull/787)).

The [OP tsega](https://stackoverflow.com/users/435540/tsega) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24236829/how-to-structure-github-wiki-files/24237161?noredirect=1#comment37435841_24237161):

> tried to look into the Gollum wiki myself and it turns out **you can organize your files under directories but that will not be how you access them**.
>
> **Every page is accessed from the root of the wiki**,e.g. `github.com/user/repo/wiki/file-name` not `github.com/user/repo/wiki/directory/file-name`.
>
> The file names should be unique, and if you want to have proper titles they need to be capitalized and dashed (not underscored).

Comment: Thanks @VonC for the answer, tried to look into the [Gollum wiki](https://github.com/gollum/gollum/wiki) myself and it turns out you can organize your files under directories but that will not be how you access them. Every page is accessed from the root of the wiki,e.g. `github.com/user/repo/wiki/file-name` not  `github.com/user/repo/wiki/directory/file-name`. The file names should be unique, and if you want to have proper titles they need to be capitalized and dashed (not underscored). Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @tsega Ok. I have added your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 2):

I've just hit the same problem and I've solved it (kinda) using a **custom menu bar**, and using regular Markdown, i.e. headers and links to create a folder structure.

Comment: Can you please send an example?

Comment: @NoamPeled For example, [spring framwork](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki)

Comment: -1 because this doesn't actually handle page organization, it just combines pages. This is only practical for a low amount of content/pages.

Answer (score 2):

In 2022 this is still not possible.
Please upvote [this feature request](https://github.com/community/community/discussions/23914)

Comment: We ended up putting our wiki in the core repo. There we can make the hierarchy as we want.